# from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array ImportError: cannot import name 'img_to_array' from 'keras.preprocessing.image

Tags: python, keras

i have a problem,every i run this code pls help guys

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import os
import numpy as np
# Keras
from keras.models import load_model
# Flask utils
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from flask import jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import pickle
import cv2
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
```

[This Is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4p5K.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also, please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

try importing like this (underscore instead of dot):

```
from keras_preprocessing.image import img_to_array
```